# Como imprimir um fomulario contendo tabelas (grade) via c#

Tags: c#, winforms, itextsharp, print

estou precisando gerar uma impressão de carnê de crediario parecido com este que se encontra em anexo. Não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer isso, qual ferramenta usar. Alguem poderia me dar uma dica?

Muito obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderá fazer isso utilizando o PrintDocument. O evento _PrintPage do objeto PrintDocument possui como parâmetro PrintPageEventArgs que possibilita desenhar Strings e Linhas no seu documento para impressão.

Para escrever Strings no documento para impressão utilize:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(string S, font Font, Brush brush, PointF point);
```

Para desenhar linhas utilize:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pen pen, Point pt1, Point pt2);
```

Recomendo a leitura dos seguintes artigos:
Como imprimir documentos - Macoratti:
http://www.macoratti.net/09/09/c_prn1.htm

Como imprimir documentos - MSDN:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Função DrawLine MSDN:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Davi, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Abraço.